# Can "A (logically) implies B" and "not-A (logically) implies B" be both true?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have the following statements. They are logical implications.

1) A implies B.

2) Not A implies B.

Can they both be true? I think no because if one of them is true then also its contrapositive is true. So if both are true then A and not A would be true. But this clearly violates the law of excluded middle.

Comment: If A is False and B is True we have that "A to B" is True and also "not A to B" is True.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited they question. I was referring to logical not material implications.

Comment: The answer is again Yes. if B is a tautology.

Comment: So we could say that "if not B then A or not A"? (Exclusive or)

Comment: If both A➔B and ¬A➔B then B is always true (a tautology, as Mauro said). Asserting ¬B is assuming a false premise.

Comment: Yes; A or not-A is always TRUE. Thus, "if B, then (A or not-A)" is always TRUE, for $B$ whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A⊨B (A logically entail B) and ¬A⊨B (not-A logically entails B) are both true when (and only when) B is a tautology. So, yes, they can both be true.

You write:

> I think no because if one of them is true then also its contrapositive is true. So if both are true then A and not A would be true.

No. The contrapositives are ¬B⊨¬A and ¬B⊨A. The contrapositives are also true when B is a tautology, but that doesn't mean that both A and ¬A would be true in that case. It just means that ¬B is a contradiction, which is to be expected if B is a tautology.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation as to the fact that the asssertion means that B is a tautology. I can prove it using a truth table, but cannot provide an argument.

Comment: @RayLittleRock If we assume A, B is true. If we assume not-A, B is true. Since A and not-A exhaust all possibilities, it means that B is true in every possible case, thus a tautology.

Comment: Now that you say it ... Thanks.

Comment: @RayLittleRock If B is necessarily true then its truth does not depend on A.

Comment: @Eliran I constructed the truth table and find that  (A⊨B and ¬A⊨B)⊨B is always true. So why B is the tautology and not the statement (A⊨B and ¬A⊨B)⊨B?

Comment: @adosar "⊨" is not a *connective*, it doesn't have a truth table. You are probably mistaking it for the conditional "→".

Answer (score 0):

- Saying that a proposition X logically implies proposition Y means that *( X-->Y)* is true in all possible cases, or, equivalently, that its negation , manely ( *X&~Y)* , implies absurdity. So the propsoition  ' *X |=Y*' it can be translated as

*(X & ~Y)  <--> Falsum*

which imples that

*(X & ~Y)  --> Falsum*

Note : Falsum ( symbol : **a reversed *T*** )  is the proposiitonal logic constant that is equivalent to any antilogy.

- Saying that a proposition *X* is a tautology is equivalent to saying that its negation is equivalent to Falsum.
- The truth tables above show

(1) that '  both A|=B and ~A|=B ' is not a contradictory sentence, since it is true in 2 cases .

(2) that the sentence '  both A|=B and ~A|=B ' is equivalent to the sentence ' B is a tautology' ( that is,  not-B is equivalent to Falsum)

[image]

[image]